# Intellij is very slow when opening js files

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I am using intellij Ultimate 2016, everything works fine except when I open js file and also with the structure view opened. It would become fast when I close the structure view. Does any hit this issue too ? Any solution for it ? Thanks

Comment: 3rd party plug-ins are often to blame for performance issues. So you may want to try disabling any you have installed. If that does not solve it, you can follow the steps in this JetBrains document:  [Reporting performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems)